# are there dangers in using multiple pacakage managers

Tags: linux, package-management

Would using other distros' package managers to install programs cause an issue?  eg: installing of rpm packages on Debian based system, or pacman packages on Red Hat.

I use parrot sec and I have the rpm and snaps package managers installed.  But I mainly use the apt since its the default package manager but apt being a wonderful package manager does not have every program.

So would installing programs from other distro based package manager cause an issue?

Comment: "... but apt being a wonderful package manager does not have every program" no package manager has "every program". Not until you add a ton of repositories. Moot argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best ways of breaking a distribution is to try and use another distribution's packages seamlessly. Just because Parrot has `apt` and Debian has `apt` does not mean that they'll play together well. Different distributions may version-number the packages differently, and you could find that installing a Debian package pulls in any number of differently-numbered dependencies from Parrot. Or you might find that Debian needs a package that Parrot doesn't even have, and vice versa.

Not a good idea, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Snap package manager shouldn't be a problem, single files are used and virtual file systems. The same applies for Flatpak or Appimages, in case you need an app available only over there.

But you also mentioned RPMs. These could produce problems. They shouldn't be used on Debian and derivatives like ParrotOS.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, this is almost always going to break your system unless you take special steps to avoid that situation. All distribution package managers (as opposed to language PM's like NPM or PIP) are designed to operate under the assumption that they have 100% control over a vast majority of the filesystem outside of `/usr/local` and `/home`, and they break things pretty reliably when that assumption is not met. In fact, even just manually building and installing software independent of the package manager can be risky (this is why sane admins use `/usr/local` for such things).

However, that doesn't mean you can't use software that is not packaged for your distribution:

- If it has a Flatpak, AppImage, or Snap package, you can almost always use that safely provided your distro can support the requirements for those formats (almost all major ones support AppImage out of the box, and Flatpak and/or Snap with minimal effort).
- The software might be available as a Docker image, which you can use not only on any Linux distro which provides Docker, but also on Windows or macOS.
- You could also potentially create your own Docker image for the software by just using a regular OS container as a base.
- Most sane package managers allow you to install into a user configurable prefix instead of the root filesystem (though this is not always exposed on the user-facing tools like APT or DNF). This can be used to create a chroot environment you can then run the desired software from.
- Provided it's FOSS, you can usually build from source for your distribution. Just make sure to configure it to put stuff in `/usr/local` so that you don't interfere with the package manager (and possibly look into [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/), it makes managing stuff like this much easier).